# aiohttp with aiohttp-devtools hot reload

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp, hot-reload

I want a similar reloading to what django `runserver` does.
If I change a python file I want the application to reload.
I've installed `aiohttp-devtools` and run with `adev runserver`, yet no reload when I change python files.
Just to be clear, I'm not talking about browser refresh, just the python reloading. I will click the refresh button in the browser myself.

Answer (score 3):

from [aiohttp docs](https://tutorialedge.net/python/create-rest-api-python-aiohttp/), something like

```
## filename: app.py

from aiohttp import web
import json

async def handle(request):
    response_obj = { 'status' : 'success' }
    return web.Response(text=json.dumps(response_obj))

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/', handle)
if __name__ == '__main__': web.run_app(app)
```

and then, [based on aiohttp-devtools](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-devtools#runserver), in the project directory:

```
 adev runserver .
```